# Слово "зря"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а какова этимология слова "зря" в значении "попусту"? Мне на ум приходит слово "зрить" — то есть, "видеть", но это совершенно другое значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит от праслав. *зьрѧ — прич. наст. вр. от зреть, первонач. «праздно смотря». Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Answer (score 2):

Ну да. Зря - деепричастиие от зреть и одновременно наречие, синонимичное "попусту".
Именнно "(напрасно) зря" и было исходной формой.